# C# How to preserve process across different users

Tags: c#, c, wpf

For school I have to develop anti-malware software using a different approach than most other software. Instead of blacklisting harmful software, we have to whitelist programs and prevent the execution of non-whitelisted software. We've written a driver in C and the rest of the program using C# and WPF. The driver is stable and the program is doing a pretty good job. But we have one huge issue. We can't switch users.

The computer freezes as soon as we try to switch users (doesn't happen when the program is not running). We've been looking across the internet for quite some time now and we didn't find any valuable help regarding this issue.

My questions now:

- How can we find out when the computer is about to switch user.
- When this happens, how can we "pause" the process, switch user, and resume the software on that user without running the software twice (once for each user).

*I can't include code because we're bound to a non-disclosure agreement regarding the source code.

Comment: You have an *NDA* for a *school assignment*? Seriously?

Comment: We're developing this for a real company. @LucasTrzesniewski

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: I believe you will have to run as a Windows Service to achieve this functionality - Achieving it any other way would in and of itself be a *malware activity*.

Comment: The driver should probably run as Windows Service under the LocalService or LocalSystem account.

Comment: Is it at all wise to restart a piece of software following a user change? It has to be presumed that the new user doesn't know anything about what the last user was doing. At the very least that's going to be confusing.

Comment: @goobering anti-malware software should always run system-wide.. Each user has to be protected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the SystemEvents.SessionEnding and SystemEvents.SessionSwitch events to detect system shutdowns and user changes.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionswitch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

It sounds to me as if at least parts of your program should be running as a service. Services only run one instance per machine, so there would be no need to pause and reset anything for different users.

Comment: We've been building on your idea. We didn't develop a service. But we listen for these sessionswitches. We close or open the driver regarding the given event.